# Solving $ y(x)-2-\int_0^x e^{y(t)-t} \, dt = 0 $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

So, I'm trying to solve the following differential equation methodically:

$$ y(x)-2-\int_0^x e^{y(t)-t} \, dt = 0 $$

I rearranged the equation a bit and differentiated both sides and got:

$$ e^x \cdot y'(x)=e^{y(x)} $$

Now,  I immediately see that a possible solution is $ y(x) = x $, but how do I solve this more methodically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of variables:
$$ e^x \cdot y'=e^{y} $$
$$ e^x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{y} $$
$$ e^{-y} \cdot \frac{dy}{dx}=e^{-x} $$
$$\int e^{-y} \, dy=\int e^{-x} \, dx$$

Comment: Wow, that was embarrassingly easy. Thank you!